# How to correctly output strings with ruamel.yaml

Tags: python, ruamel.yaml

I'm trying to use ruamel to update some dependabot files.

Dependabot requires that the time is a string.
`The property '#/updates/0/schedule/time' of type integer did not match the following type: string`

The following code can reproduce the missbehavior:

```
import ruamel.yaml, sys
test = "time: 09:00"
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.dump(test, sys.stdout)
```

Gives:

```
'time: 09:00'
```

Shouldn't it be something like?

```
'time: "09:00"'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output is correct YAML. Since you dump a string and your
string includes a colon (YAML's value indicator) followed by a space, you get quotes around
your output, because otherwise the input would be read back as a dict.

To get quotes around the `09:00` they have to be present in your input string:

```
import ruamel.yaml, sys
test = "time: \"09:00\""
yaml.dump(test, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
'time: "09:00"'
```

If you don't want a single string as output, then don't dump a string, but a dict

```
test = dict(time="09:00")
yaml.dump(test, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
time: 09:00
```

Since it is not necessary to put quotes around `09:00` in this case, `ruamel.yaml` doesn't
put them there. You can force them just around `09:00` (and not around `time`) by
creating a double-quoted string item, and dump that:

```
DQ = ruamel.yaml.scalarstring.DoubleQuotedScalarString
test = dict(time=DQ("09:00"))
yaml.dump(test, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
time: "09:00"
```