# How can I preserve or add quotes around values in a YAML file without stripping comments as a side effect using ruamel.yaml?

Tags: python, python-3.x, yaml, ruamel.yaml

I am trying to generate a YAML file, which does not fall foul of the Norway problem described here: https://hitchdev.com/strictyaml/why/implicit-typing-removed/

I am running ruamel.yaml 0.17.21 in python 3.8.

Here is the code I am running:

```
import sys
from ruamel.yaml import YAML, round_trip_dump

data = [
    [1, """first value""", "first comment"],
    [2, '"second value"', "second comment"],
    ["abc", "None", 'this is a "comment"'],
    ["""def1""", "None", 'this is a "comment"'],
]
yaml = YAML()
yaml.preserve_quotes = True
code = yaml.load(
    """\
    en:
    """
)
for i, item in enumerate(data):
    code.insert(i + 1, str(item[0]), "" + str(item[1]) + "", comment=item[2])

print("\nthis strips quotes; but preserves comments:")
yaml.dump(code, sys.stdout)

print("\nthis preserves quotes; but strips comments:")
round_trip_dump(code, sys.stdout, default_style="'")

print("\ndesired result:")
print(
    "'en':\n
    '1': 'first value'  # first comment\n
    '2': 'second value' # second comment\n
    'abc': 'None' # this is a ""comment""\n
    'def1': 'None' # this is a ""comment"""
)
```

Comment: This is a Q&A site. So an actual question (as in a sentence ending with a question mark) is obligatory. Also explain why you use `round_trip_dump` which is part of  a deprecated API, while you are obviously aware of the new API ( `yaml = YAML()`. You should not use `round_trip_dump()` and certainly not try to dump data loaded with the new API and dump with the old one.

Comment: Given your data, is the use of a YAML library actually required to produce your result or is this just a simplified example that does not utilize other aspects of the library that you require?

Comment: In answer to JonSG, this is a cut down version of a bigger project. The bigger project is to extract columns from an Excel spreadsheet in order to translate them. We have found that YAML is a good interchange format. Sometimes; but not always, we have comments in one of the columns. Hence, the reason we do not use JSON as there is lack of support for comments.

Comment: In answer to Anton, I only used round_trip_dump to illustrate that the deprecated version had part of the solution I am looking for, ie the ability to surround the value in quotes. I have been unable to find this feature in the new API dump,

Comment: Further to Anton, the problem could be restated as: "How can I preserve or add quotes around values without stripping comments as a side effect using ruamel.yaml?"

Comment: @Ian The typical thing to do if your post is below par is edit it so it is clear. You e.g. also want to look at the last print statement in your code (which throws  an error (use triple single quotes?)), so it is hard to see what you want to do. Search for `SingleQuotedScalarString` on SO, e.g. [Preserve quotes and also add data with quotes in Ruamel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39263202/1307905)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Anthon and @JonSG for constructive feedback. Based on that, I found this article [How to correctly output strings with ruamel.yaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69270877/how-to-correctly-output-strings-with-ruamel-yaml)

My working solution is therefore:

```
import sys
from ruamel.yaml import YAML, scalarstring

DQ = scalarstring.DoubleQuotedScalarString

data = [
    [1, """first value""", "first comment"],
    [2, '"second value"', "second comment"],
    ["abc", "None", 'this is a "comment"'],
    ["""def1""", "None", 'this is a "comment"'],
]
yaml = YAML()
code = yaml.load(
    """\
    en:
    """
)
for i, item in enumerate(data):
    code.insert(i + 1, DQ(item[0]), DQ(str(item[1])), comment=item[2])

yaml.dump(code, sys.stdout)

"""
which produces:

en:
"1": "first value"  # first comment
"2": "\"second value\"" # second comment
"abc": "None" # this is a "comment"
"def1": "None" # this is a "comment"
"""
```